# One-time resolving promise singleton (Angular service)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

The question applies to promises in general and isn't specific to Angular, but the example makes use of Angular $q and service singletons.

Here is [a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6PrmlghVKsbfuLCLRN8Q?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.factory('onetimeResolvingService', function ($q) {
  var promise = $q(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve();
    }, 500);
  });

  return promise;
});

app.controller('AController', function (onetimeResolvingService, $q) {
  onetimeResolvingService.then(function () {
    console.log('A resolved');
    return $q.reject();
  }).then(function () {
    console.log('A resolved');
  });
});

app.controller('BController', function (onetimeResolvingService, $q) {
  onetimeResolvingService.then(function () {
    console.log('B resolved');
    return $q.reject();
  }).then(function () {
    console.log('B resolved');
  });
});
```

and the document is

```
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="AController"></div>
    <div ng-controller="BController"></div>
  </body>
```

It will naturally output

> A resolved
>
> B resolved

What would be a good pattern to make the singleton promise resolve only the first time, i.e.

> A resolved

and not the subsequent times?

Something like `onetimeResolvingService.$$state.status = 2` could possibly can do the trick, but it looks like $q hack and smells bad.

Comment: From what I read, it doesn't work the way you think. The singleton promise resolves only once. However, two independent .thens, one in each controller, are chained to the promise. The two .thens (more accurately their callbacks) are guaranteed always to respond to the *same* settlement state - resolved or rejected. Of course, the two controllers can be completely different from each other in the way they respond to settlement, but that is just stating the obvious.

Comment: This can be done now with Promise.resolve() (see below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T.J. Crowder is correct in that the functionality you're looking for in a promise does not exist.  The question of how to achieve what you're looking for however can be found in a structure like below:

```
    function OnetimeValue($q) {
        var promisedValue = $q(function(resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function () {resolve('The one time value');}, 500);
        });

        var valueGot = false;
        this.GetValue = function GetValue() {
            var res;
            if (!valueGot) {
                res = promisedValue;
            } else {
                res = $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                    resolve(null);
                });
            }
            valueGot = true;

            return res;
        };
    }
```

Assuming you `new` this once (as angular services do), GetValue() will return the promisified string upon the first call.  Subsequent calls return null.

[This plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FOOuYb4KRZfrrCHey8Cz?p=preview) shows the above in action

Comment: I guess it has to be `else { res = $q(function(resolve, reject) { reject(); }); }` in my case to skip the validation in `GetValue().then`, but the idea is good and seems to be the only reasonable solution, I tend to the similar one.

Comment: Just make sure you don't reject a promise for control-flow purposes.  Semantically, reject indicates that an error occurred.  So if it is in fact an error in your domain logic to access this value more than once then go for it.

Comment: Not so much a "one time value" as a "value after the first time will be `null`" :-)

Comment: Ha - well without the domain knowledge it's hard to guess what makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

> What would be a good pattern to make the singleton promise resolve only the first time

To not to. One of the key facets of a promise is that once it's settled, it's settled, and both the settled state (resolved or rejected) and the value are at that point unchanging. See §2.1.2 and §2.1.3 of [the A+ promises spec](https://promisesaplus.com/):

> 2.1.2 When fulfilled, a promise:
>
> 2.1.2.1 must not transition to any other state.
>
> 2.1.2.2 must have a value, which must not change.
>
> 2.1.3 When rejected, a promise:
>
> 2.1.3.1 must not transition to any other state.
>
> 2.1.3.2 must have a reason, which must not change.

If the callbacks added via `then` are not satisfied at some stage (e.g., your second hookup), it's not a promise. It's something...else.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Whoops, misread the question.

---

There is now a way to do this with EcmaScript promises.  The static Promise.resolve() method takes a promise and waits on its value; if it has already been resolved, it simply returns the value.

For example, here's how we're using this method to make multiple calls to fetchQuery rely on a single async authentication call:

fetchQuery gets an auth token (JWT) with:

```
const authToken = await AuthToken.get();
```

And AuthToken looks like (TypeScript):

```
class AuthToken {
  private static _accessTokenPromise: Promise<string>;

  public static async get() {
    if (!this._accessTokenPromise)
      this._accessTokenPromise = this.AuthFunction(); // AuthFunction returns a promise

    return await Promise.resolve(this._accessTokenPromise);
  }
}
```

Or simply call then() twice on the same promise object per the OP's question to have two calls wait on the same async operation.

Comment: This is quite old question, but I'm not sure that this wasn't my case. In fact, this the behaviour that had to be avoided. In your example `AuthToken.get().then(() => console.log('foo'); AuthToken.get().then(() => console.log('bar')` will result in 'foo bar' output. While the expected behaviour is 'foo'. This is what 'one-time resolving' refers to and this is what the example in OP illustrates.

Comment: @estus You're right, on a closer read the OP is asking for the opposite behavior of what I wanted (prevent this() being called twice, vs. call this() twice to get two places in code waiting on the same async operation).

Comment: This actually was my old-time question, just was curious how this promise pattern can be implemented (the pattern proved itself nonviable in fact).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `lodash` you can simply use `memoize` like this:

```js
const returnFirstRunResultAlways = _.memoize(async function(params) { ... })
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is the same issue as described in comments to this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/44056843/3731501 . The question describes a different behaviour rather than the answer provides.